# Creating a binary word search 

Tags: javascript, performance, html, css

I recently crafted [a binary word search puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/111576/a-pretty-binary-grid) using HTML, CSS and JavaScript to dynamically build grids within a grid:

```js
var board = document.getElementById('board');
var characters = [
    'H','U','O','M','S','F','I','R','E','I',
    'P','O','B','P','O','S','P','K','K','A',
    'S','E','P','T','E','M','B','E','R','F',
    'Y','T','A','E','W','D','T','I','O','T',
    'W','W','N','S','R','A','I','E','B','E',
    'X','E','H','P','T','A','Y','Z','S','R',
    'S','L','X','G','Y','E','T','U','F','N',
    'K','F','D','R','E','Q','R','I','X','O',
    'Y','T','H','Q','Z','H','X','N','O','O',
    'L','H','Z','D','F','O','U','R','T','N'
];
for (var iCharacters = 0; iCharacters < characters.length; iCharacters++) {
    var binary = '0' + characters[iCharacters].charCodeAt(0).toString(2);
    var square = '<div class="square">';
    for (var iBinary = 0; iBinary < binary.length; iBinary++) {
        if (iBinary == 4) {
            square += '<div class="empty"></div>';
            square += '<div>' + binary.charAt(iBinary) + '</div>';
        }
        else
            square += '<div>' + binary.charAt(iBinary) + '</div>';
    }
    board.innerHTML += square + '</div>';
}
```

```css
html, body {
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #00C9FF 0%, #92FE9D 100%);
}
.board {
    width: 800px;
    height: 800px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 10%);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(10, 10%);
    grid-gap: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.square {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 33%);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 33%);
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #fff7;
}
.square div {
    display: flex;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #444;
}
.square div:nth-child(1) { border-top-left-radius: 5px; }
.square div:nth-child(3) { border-top-right-radius: 5px; }
.square div:nth-child(7) { border-bottom-left-radius: 5px; }
.square div:nth-child(9) { border-bottom-right-radius: 5px; }
.square .empty {
    background-color: #0003;
    border-radius:5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="board" class="board"></div>
```

Since I don't use HTML, CSS and JavaScript as often as I used to, it would be nice to have someone review my code to answer the following questions:

- Is my code legible?
- Are there more efficient methods I could have used?

<sub>***Note**: The use of Hungarian notation isn't something I typically do, however in the case where I have multiple iteration variables, I utilize the notation to help denote that the variable I'm working with is, an iteration variable. As such `iBinary` does not mean that it is an integer, but rather an iteration variable. To me, this is easier to follow when it doesn't make sense to use `x,y,z` or `i,j,k`.*</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Review

You code looks very old school. Use modern JavaScript that simplifies common tasks and helps improve performance.

#### General points

- Use constants for variables that do not change. `characters`, `board`, `binary` should all be `const`
- Names are a little long. Use common abbreviations when possible. eg for programmers `characters` is written `chars`, `binary` is `bin`. Loop index's are short `iBinary` can just be `i`, `idx`, or `j`
- Use `for of` when you don't need the indexes.
- Avoid writing markup to the page. It is very slow compared to using the DOM API. see rewrite
- Use [=== (Strict equality)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality) rather than [== (Equality)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality). Same for [!== (Strict inequality)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_inequality) rather than [!= (Inequality)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Inequality)
- Dont repeat code. The two statement blocks inside the loop both end in the same line. Remove the `else` and the line `square += '<div>' + binary.charAt(iBinary) + '</div>';` need only be written once.
- ALWAYS delimit code blocks. eg never do `else foo = 0;` always `else { foo = 0; }` same with `if`, `for`, `while`, etc..

### Rewrite

The rewrite does not resemble your code at all as it uses modern JavaScript.

The code is packed into a function as you should never write code outside a function.

```js
;(() => {
    "use strict";
    const tag = (tag, props = {}) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), props);
    const append = (par, ...sibs) => sibs.reduce((p, sib) => (p.appendChild(sib), p), par);
    const rows = [
        'HUOMSFIREI',
        'POBPOSPKKA',
        'SEPTEMBERF',
        'YTAEWDTIOT',
        'WWNSRAIEBE',
        'XEHPTAYZSR',
        'SLXGYETUFN',
        'KFDREQRIXO',
        'YTHQZHXNOO',
        'LHZDFOURTN'
    ];
    const char2BinArr = c => [...c.charCodeAt(0).toString(2).padStart(8, "0")];
    function addBin(bit, i) {
        const res = [tag("div", {textContent: bit})];
        i === 4 && res.unshift(tag("div", {className: "empty"}));
        return res;
    }
    function createBoard(rows) {
        append(board, 
            ...rows.map(row => [...row].map(char => {
                return append(
                    tag("div", {className: "square"}),
                    ...char2BinArr(char).map(addBin).flat()
                );
            })).flat()
        );
    }
    createBoard(rows);
})();
```

```css
html, body {
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #00C9FF 0%, #92FE9D 100%);
}
.board {
    width: 800px;
    height: 800px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 10%);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(10, 10%);
    grid-gap: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.square {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 33%);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 33%);
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #fff7;
}
.square div {
    display: flex;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #444;
}
.square div:nth-child(1) { border-top-left-radius: 5px; }
.square div:nth-child(3) { border-top-right-radius: 5px; }
.square div:nth-child(7) { border-bottom-left-radius: 5px; }
.square div:nth-child(9) { border-bottom-right-radius: 5px; }
.square .empty {
    background-color: #0003;
    border-radius:5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="board" class="board"></div>
```

### References

Reference to features used in the rewrite.

- JS objects and function calls

  - [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
  - [Array.flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)
  - [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
  - [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)
  - [String.padStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart)
- JS operators

  - [... (Spread syntax)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)
  - [=== (Strict equality)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality)
- JS misc

  - [=> (Arrow functions)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)
- Browser API's

  - [Document.createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)
  - [Node.appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

Answer (score 2):

Answering to your first question your code is certainly legible, I would modify your main structure (I'm copying just the first two rows for brevity):

```
var characters = ['H','U','O','M','S','F','I','R','E','I',
    'P','O','B','P','O','S','P','K','K','A',
];
```

You could separate the two rows in your matrix with a clean cut using differents strings for every row and with [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join?retiredLocale=it#select-language) and [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) methods:

```
const characters = ['HUOMSFIREI','POBPOSPKKA'].join('').split('');
```

I saw you used only `var` in your code, this is legitimate but if you have the possibility better use `let` and `const` instead of it for a better clarity of your code and to avoid problems related to the scope, see [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var?retiredLocale=it) for more informations.

About your loop:

```
for (var iCharacters = 0; iCharacters < characters.length; iCharacters++) {
    var binary = '0' + characters[iCharacters].charCodeAt(0).toString(2);
    var square = '<div class="square">';
    for (var iBinary = 0; iBinary < binary.length; iBinary++) {
        if (iBinary == 4) {
            square += '<div class="empty"></div>';
            square += '<div>' + binary.charAt(iBinary) + '</div>';
        }
        else
            square += '<div>' + binary.charAt(iBinary) + '</div>';
    }
    board.innerHTML += square + '</div>';
}
```

The line `square += '<div>' + binary.charAt(iBinary) + '</div>';` is present in both the two branches of your if-else statement, you can rewrite it like below :

```
if (iBinary === 4) {
   square += '<div class="empty"></div>';
}
square += '<div>' + binary.charAt(iBinary) + '</div>';
```

You can also use the [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of?retiredLocale=it) statement and rewrite your loop in this way:

```
for (const character of characters) {
    const binary = '0' + character.charCodeAt(0).toString(2);
    let square = '<div class="square">';

    for (let iBinary = 0; iBinary < binary.length; ++iBinary) {
        if (iBinary === 4) {
            square += '<div class="empty"></div>';
        }
        square += '<div>' + binary.charAt(iBinary) + '</div>';
    }
    board += square + '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For the first question, i.e.

> *Is my code legible?*

It is somewhat legible. I can understand what it is doing. Bearing in mind you stated you don't typically use Hungarian notation I'd point out that the naming could be improved. For e

Have you seen [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/111972/1575353) to [the SO post *Why shouldn't I use "Hungarian Notation"?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/111933/1575353) as well as other answers? The accepted answer points out that often Apps Hungarian is used instead of (non-Apps) Hungarian.

When I see a variable name like `iCharacters` my first thought might be that it holds the total number of characters in the array. However I can see that it is used as a counter variable incremented from 0 to one less than the total number of characters in the array. A more appropriate name might be something like `iCharacterIndex` or `iCurrentCharacterIndex`.

Then variables like `board`, `characters`, etc. don't use Hungarian notation (which I prefer). It is better to either exclusively use it or not.

The spacing is consistent with idiomatic JavaScript.

---

For the second question, i.e.

> *Are there more efficient methods I could have used?*

Just as I mentioned in [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/262781/120114) it is wise to  [Minimize browser reflows](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/browser-reflow). That means instead of adding elements to the DOM in a loop - e.g. appending to `board.innerHTML` at the end of the outer `for` loop, add elements to a [documentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) or temporary element and then add the contents of that element in a single step.

In the past there were [discussions about the most efficient way to concatenate strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16696632/1575353). Browsers have come a long way in the past decade and that may not really be a major concern anymore, especially since this code likely only runs once when the page loads. Also, [Ecmascript 6 template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) can help.

Another option might be using a [`<template>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) tag to create elements without an inner loop.